# tomcat 404 error, but it works within eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, http-status-code-404

I started programming with Spring framework.
I made a dynamic web project in eclipse, and it works well on the server that started from eclipse. After success on it, I stopped the server in eclipse, and run tomcat itself by executing [Tomcat directory]/bin/Tomcat7.exe. Then, localhost:8080 page works well, but my project pages don't work with 404 error. The path I put in is same when using server from eclipse and using server itself(based WINDOW). What should I do resolve this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:
1. copying your application war to /PATH_TO_TOMCAT_HOME/webapps. This should deploy your application to your tomcat directory.
OR
2. set "Use Tomcat installation (takes control of Tomcat installation)" in your servers settings.Probably you have selected the "Use workspace metadata..." which comes by default.

[image]